# WPF "collection contains" type databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

Considering following (simplified)model:

```
class Person {
  List<Role> Roles { get; set; } //m:n navigation property
}

class PersonVM {
  Person CurrentPerson { get; set; }
  List<Role> AllRoles { get { return dbctx.Roles; } }
}
```

how can I set up databinding showing `AllRoles` with checkboxes that are (un)checked depending whether `CurrentPerson.Roles` "contains" the role *and* (directly) modifying `CurrentPerson.Roles`, adding/removing `Role`s accordingly?
As of now I have a helper collection of `ItemAndChecked<T>`

```
class ItemAndChecked<T>
{
  public T Item { get; set; }
  public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

that I copy the `AllRoles` into and set `IsChecked` accordingly. Bind the helper collection and just before saving the model, update the original collection "manually". However this solution introduces issues with model consistency. Is there a way to bind `CurrentPerson.Roles` so it is modified directly (in the db context)?

---

edit: there are some great suggestions in comments below

Comment: You probably want to use a value converter so you can handle the special binding logic

Comment: @GordonAllocman I am not sure what exactly do you mean? I could multibind both collections, but output should be single collection - how would be the items converted back?

Comment: In the converter you can return a boolean as to whether it would be checked or not. When an item is checked you can add it to the roles in the convertback

Comment: @GordonAllocman the problem I see is, that in Convert, I can have both collections, converting it to a ItemAndChecked type of collection. But in `object[] ConvertBack(object value,` there would be just the ItemAndChecked collection to be converted back, I would not have the original reference to be updated, right?

Comment: I would consider writing a class that has a reference to a Role, and a reference to the target Person's Roles collection. Call it `RoleVM`. `Person.Roles` would have to be 'ObservableCollection<Role>`, `Person` would have `ObservableCollection<RoleVM>`. When you set `RoleVM.IsSelected`, the setter ensures that the `RoleVM`'s Role is, or is not (as appropriate), included in the Person's Roles. This is not as purely MVVM as Gordon's idea but it might be less trouble.

Comment: @wondra you can send a parameter into your convert and convertback functions

Comment: @Gordon Allocman paramter cannot use databinding, can it?

Comment: There are some good suggestions, sadly cannot verify them right now(but later today). Also please, if possible, post the suggestions as answers (rather than comments).